# JsPDF not rendering images from aws s3

Tags: javascript, html, angular, pdf, jspdf

I am working on a project and trying to generate the pdf of an invoice, i am using htmlToImage plugin with jsPDF.
This is my function

```
    let invoice = document.getElementById('invoice-detail');
    htmlToImage.toPng(invoice)
      .then((dataUrl) => {
        const img = new Image();
        img.src = dataUrl;
        const pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', [210,200]);
        let width = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
        let height = pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight();
        pdf.addImage(img, 'PNG', 0, 0, width, height);
        pdf.save('invoice' + '_' + this.invoiceDetail.invoice_no + '.pdf');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('oops, something went wrong!', error);
      });
  }
```

i have a logo on top of my invoice that is coming from aws s3 in my html file and it's not rendering on the pdf. If i use base64 it will render but normal online url won't work. Sometimes it renders but sometimes it does not. I really cannot understand the issue please any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if it renders sometimes, then I would guess that the problem is likely the image is not fully loaded yet when you are creating the pdf

Comment: Now it's not loading even once. It's always giving the same problem

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "If i use base64 it will render but normal online url won't work"?